# Running an Http Server in Background in iOS

Tags: ios, httpserver

I am currently building an app that serves as an http server for wifi speakers to download and play music from it. I know clearly that app resources are killed after a short time one they gone off to the background. is there any way to maintain the connection between http server and the devices that are fetching data from it? I need a legal way, because this app is to be submitted to the app store. I tried searching over the net, and I found the solutions they provided seems to be likely rejected by apple.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Normally apps can't continually run in the background. However there are a few background modes that do permit it (with some caveats and limitations). One of these is audio, however in your case it is not the app itself that is playing audio, rather it is enabling it, so it is unclear if your app could legally use the background audio mode to enable background execution. You can also look into airplay

Comment: I highly doubt you'll be able to find an answer on here. People can only guess. And there is no way of asking Apple in advance if it will be permitted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use the Audio and AirPlay background mode available in iOS.

Whether they accept a HTTP server being part of the app only time can tell.

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Failing that other background modes (such as Bluetooth / VOIP) can be used as workarounds but they may not allow during review.

Comment: I read through that document awhile ago and there it states that if you are going to use the Audio and AirPlay background then your app should play something that can be heard, no silent songs. And yeah, using other tricks would be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Also, just marking your app as an audio app isn't sufficient, you have to use the player APIs

Comment: @Matt__C what does this involve? Just looping an AVAudioPlayer indefinitely?

Comment: I'm just running this on my own iPad, pretty surprising I can't give my own app permission to do this. Do I then also need to start a background task or is this counterproductive?

Comment: @DennisL It's been a long time so I don't remember all the details but I know that the background audio route didn't work for me - I seem to recall that the app would still get randomly suspended. I did get a background http server working by running a location manager using high accuracy, though. Hope that helps!